# Get elements by id array and order by this array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I want te get, for example, products by id array but I want these products on same order that id array.

For example, I want products with id 6, 3, 8:

```
ids = [6, 3, 8]
Product.where(id: ids)
```

It gives me products but the first is product with id = 3, second with id = 6...

And I want these products in same order that `ids` array. I want the first product with id = 6, the second with id = 3...

How could I do that in Products query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in one ActiveRecord query, it depends on the RDBMS you are using and will include a raw sql string in the `order` method, but you can also do this in plain ruby:

```
Product.where(id: ids).sort_by { |item| ids.index(item.id) }
```

P.S. After sorting class of the collection is going to change from `ActiveRecord_Relation` to `Array`.

Comment: Thx! Works great!

Comment: Super inefficient with big size of ids array.

Comment: @Ilya: it is just a very inefficient thing to do in general, no matter where, on the application or db side.

Comment: And what is the most efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Indexing should work:

```
Product.where(id: ids).index_by(&:id).values_at(*ids)
```

Or just (checked in MySQL, but sanitize `ids` before if ids are coming from external source):

```
Product.where(id: ids).order("field(id, #{ids.join(', ')})")
```

Comment: the problem here is that `.order("field(id, #{ids.join(', ')})")` is a very bad thing to do, because this way the activerecord engine doesn't escape the input. for example `ids  =  ["7); delete from products; select * from products where id in (7"]`

Comment: @potashin, I know what SQL injection means, thanks :) Of course, you should sanitize your input before, but it is better than nlogn algorithm anyway I believe)

Comment: @potashin which solution would be faster? If second, maybe it makes sense to escape the params of SQL query in the line before?

Comment: @Ilya: I guess if you know such things, you should at least warn people not to do so :) otherwise people can't tell the difference. What is the complexity of the `field()` usage in ordering in MySQL?

Comment: @potashin, I don't know exactly, but believe that this function is optimized (at least as my 1st variant).